# How to load images from a directory on the computer in Python

Tags: image, python-2.7, loading-image

Hello I am New to python and I wanted to know how i can load images from a directory on the computer into python variable.
I have a set of images in a folder on disk and I want to display these images in a loop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use PIL (Python Imaging Library) http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ to load images.
Then you can make an script to read images from a directory and load them to python, something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image as PImage

def loadImages(path):
    # return array of images

    imagesList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        img = PImage.open(path + image)
        loadedImages.append(img)

    return loadedImages

path = "/path/to/your/images/"

# your images in an array
imgs = loadImages(path)

for img in imgs:
    # you can show every image
    img.show()
```

Comment: The library [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) should now be used. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/39985729/6281925.

Answer (score 1):

`pip install ThreadedFileLoader` 
You can use  `ThreadedFileLoader` module. It uses threading to load images.

```py
from ThreadedFileLoader.ThreadedFileLoader import *

instance = ThreadedImageLoader("path_to_folder/*.jpg")
instance.start_loading()
images = instance.loaded_objects
print(len(images))
print(images[0].shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use glob and imageio python packages to achieve the same. Below is code in python 3:

```
import glob
import imageio

for image_path in glob.glob("<your image directory path>\\*.png"):
    im = imageio.imread(image_path)
    print (im.shape)
    print (im.dtype)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have images in your google drive, and want to load, resize and save the images, then the following code works well.

```
import os, sys
from os import listdir

from PIL import Image
from google.colab import drive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

# need to enter password to access your google drive

from google.colab import files
main_dir = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Panda/"
files = listdir(main_dir)
# you can change file extension below to read other image types
images_list = [i for i in files if i.endswith('.jpg')] ## output file names only

for idx,image in enumerate(images_list):
  print(idx)
  img = Image.open(main_dir + image)
  #print(img.size)
  #plt.imshow(img)
  img = img.resize((480, 600))
  img.save(main_dir + image)
```