# Python 3, is PIL an alias for Pillow?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Python 3.5 on Windows 7 64-bit.

I'm confused -- IF one installs *Pillow*, THEN must one use the name of the superseded / uninstalled graphics library *PIL* as an alias for it?

Per the Pillow intallation instructions (http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/installation.html), "Pillow and PIL cannot co-exist in the same environment. Before installing Pillow, please uninstall PIL." Okay:

> **D:\Python35>pip uninstall PIL**
>
> Cannot uninstall requirement PIL, not installed

Next:

> **D:\Python35>pip install Pillow**
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Pillow in d:\python35\lib\site-package

So now:

> **D:\Python35>python**
>
> Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> **import Pillow**
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "stdin", line 1, in module
>
> ImportError: No module named 'Pillow'

Okay, so if there's no *Pillow* (or *pillow*), let's try:

> **import PIL**

No error even though pip told me *PIL* wasn't installed. Next:

> **dir(PIL)**
>
> ['PILLOW_VERSION', 'VERSION', '**builtins**', '**cached**', '**doc**', '**file**', '**loader**'

Hmm, seemingly contradictory naming ala PIL versus Pillow?

> **PIL.PILLOW_VERSION**
>
> '3.4.1'

3.4.1 being as of this date the latest version of Pillow (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow)

I'm very confused -- the need to use PIL as an apparent alias for Pillow seems wrong. Yet per the above it seems to be necessary to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `pillow` library is the successor to the `PIL` library. It still uses the `PIL` package name to serve as a drop-in replacement.

- *install* `Pillow`
- `import PIL`

---

The `pip` package name and python/`import` package name do not have to be the same. Since `pillow` is meant to replace `PIL`, it uses the same `import` name for compatibility.

Comment: I'm willing to accept that but it seems so counter-intuitive: The Pillow documentation tells me that Pillow can't co-exist with PIL but then turns around and re-uses its name.So my follow-on question is, is  there a straightforward way to "import Pillow" as a way of avoiding ambiguity as to what library is being used?

Comment: @RBV It cannot coexist with PIL precisely because it is using the same name. There can be only one module installed with the `import` name `PIL` and that's either Pillow or PIL.